# How to add a var as source parameter of ImageBackground

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, require

**What i want to do**
I built an React-Native App. On the HomeScreen there is a FlatList containing 1 item. The item in the list is a Pressable, so i can click on the area and get navigated to the DetailsScreen. This DetailsScreen has the same structure for every item in the list, but the image that gets displayed is different from item to item.

**How i tried to solve it**
I connect a unique path as string to every item. When i click on a item i get navigated to the DetailsScreen. I pass the parameters to this screen with `navigation.navigate('Details', {params})`. In the DetailsScreen i save each param to a cons. Now i want the BackgroundImage item to show the image. This does not work. When i pass in a fixed path as string like `<ImageBackground source={require('./assets/foo.png')}/>` everything works.

**Error Message**
Error: App.js: Invalid call at line XYZ: require(pathToPNG)

**Code**

```
function HomeScreen( {navigation}) {

    const itemList = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'test1',
        pathToPNG: './assets/foo.png'
        
      }
    ];

    const oneItem = ( {item} ) => (
      <Pressable onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details', {id: item.id, name: item.name, pathToPNG: item.pathToPNG})}> 
        <Text style={{textAlign:'center', fontFamily:'Poppins-Regular', fontSize:30}}>
          {'foo-bar'}
        </Text>
      </Pressable>
    )

    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <FlatList style={styles.flatty}
            data = { itemList }
            renderItem = { oneItem }
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }


function DetailsScreen( {route, navigation}) {

    const {id, name, pathToPNG} = route.params;
    
    return (
        //START OF THE PROBLEM AREA
        <ImageBackground source={require(pathToPNG)}/>
        //END OF THE PROBLEM AREA
    )
}


const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();


export default function App( {navigation}) {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
        <Stack.Screen name='Home' component={HomeScreen}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From docs:  https://reactnative.dev/docs/images

> ... the image name in require has to be known statically

```js
const itemList = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'test1',
    pathToPNG: require('./assets/foo.png'), // <-- use require in itemList
  },
];

function DetailsScreen( {route, navigation}) {

    const {id, name, pathToPNG} = route.params;
    
    return (
        //START OF THE PROBLEM AREA
        <ImageBackground source={pathToPNG}/> {/* <-- do not use require with dynamic argument */}
        //END OF THE PROBLEM AREA
    )
}
```

Comment: I was so confident that i have already tried that. But it worked, thanks for the answer.